# How to show Toast when I click on the LayoutParams TextView

Tags: java, textview, android-layoutparams, android

This is single `TextView` which is containing values form database. So I want when I click on the `TextView,` it should show `Toast` the same text in the position I clicked.

[The image showing the text view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPlxr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code the  `TextView` showing the data which is coming from the firebase.

```
textView = new TextView(Chat.this);                                                                                                       
textView.setText(message);                                                                                                                  
final Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/fnt1.otf");                                                  

  textView.setTypeface(typeface);                                                                                                             
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 20);
  textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```